# How to increase icon size and buttons locations?

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I want to change the icon size of photos and folders. I realize there is an button for it, however, I might need non default values, like 120% (it goes directly from 100% to 150%). Is there a way to do so?

Second, there is a way to move the close/maximize/minimize buttons to the left side of the screen?

Many thanks.

Example of what I mean on the first question:

[image: Screenshot-at-2021-05-14-11-09-09.png]

Comment: Ubuntu release/version? Answers depend on the release number and the desktop.

Comment: Please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly so that the community can know and understand what you are exactly asking.

Comment: ubuntu-mate 18.

Comment: I already edited it.

Comment: does [this reference from MATE community](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/resize-icons-in-panel/15644) help?